# Use systemd on-demand socket activation to start rtl_fm stream

Tags: systemd, socket

I would like to start `rtl_fm` on demand for a certain frequency with `systemd` the moment I connect to a certain port.

Example:

```
rtl_fm -f 105000K -M fm -s 170k -A std -l 0 -E deemp -r 44.1k | \
ffmpeg -f s16le -ac 1 -i pipe:0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:51050
```

Ideally the port should be variable, and be mapped to the frequency.

This would allow me to have a single `systemd` service which I could use to start the stream and listen to any FM radio station. (Of course just one at a time, but that's fine for my use case of `mpd` being the client)

Is this feasible with `systemd` on-demand socket activation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, most likely.

If you can make a systemd service for it, you can almost certainly have it activated via socket by enabling the socket instead of the service itself.

The command to use would be `systemctl enable my_rtl_fm.socket` instead of `systemctl enable my_rtl_fm.service`

I use this for both `sshd` and `mpd` on my computers, to save resources when they're not in use.